# Nuxt Vue 3, cant use composition api while options api works fine

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3

when i use options api it works , but when i switch to composition api , it fails.
Nuxt project, here is the simple code.

the error i get is displaySidenav is not defind

```
<script>
import TheHeader from "../components/Navigation/TheHeader";
import TheSidenav from "../components/Navigation/TheSidenav";
import ref from "vue";

export default {
  components: {
    TheHeader,
    TheSidenav
  },
  data() {
    return {
      displaySidenav: false
    };
  }
  // setup() {
  //   const displaySidenav = ref(false);
  //   return { displaySidenav };
  // }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

i had to install npm i @nuxtjs/composition-api .
composition api is beta in nuxt.

Answer (score 0):

this line should solve your error:

`import { ref } from "vue";`

---

you can check out the [docs with an example](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#reactive-variables-with-ref) to have a reference. Keep in mind, that the composition API is supposed to be modular. So everythink you want to use, you have to import here, like `{ ref, reactive, computed, ... }`.

Comment: i tired it before i posted but anyway i checked again and this is the error i get  "export 'ref' was not found in 'vue'

Comment: which version of vue is displayed in the `package.json`?

Comment: if you are using Vue 2 (which I assume you are not), you need to use [@vue/composition-api](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/blob/master/README.md), otherwise I would check if Vue 3 is installed correctly.